# Do not trigger my method more than once

Tags: python, django

## models.py

```
class Contract(TimeStampedModel):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('customers.CustomerProfile')
    template = models.ForeignKey('configurations.ContractTemplate')
    product = models.OneToOneField('products.CustomerProduct')
    signed_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Date signed'), blank=True, null=True)
    cancelled_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Date cancelled'), blank=True,
                                        null=True)
    html_source = models.TextField(_('HTML source'), blank=True, null=True)
    pdf_file = models.OneToOneField('documents.Meta', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    blank=True, null=True)
    is_signed = models.BooleanField(_('Is signed'), default=False)
    is_cancelled = models.BooleanField(_('Is cancelled'), default=False)
    signature_uuid = models.UUIDField(_('Signature UUID'), primary_key=False,
                                      default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    signature_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(_('Signature IP'), blank=True,
                                                null=True)

...

    def sign(self, ip):
        from loanwolf.contracts.utils import render_html_contract, store_pdf_contract
        self.html_source = render_html_contract(self.template, self.customer,
                                                self.product)
        store_pdf_contract(self)
        self.signature_ip = ip
        self.signed_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.is_signed = True
        self.save()
        if self.request.state.is_signature:
            self.request.sign()
        return True
```

## views.py

```
class ContractAsHtmlView(DetailView):
    model = Contract
    pk_url_kwarg = 'uuid'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        try:
            return self.model.objects.get(
                signature_uuid=self.kwargs.get('uuid'))
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        if self.request.GET.get('lang'):
            lang = self.request.GET.get('lang')
        else:
            lang = translation.get_language_from_request(self.request)
        if self.object.template.language == lang:
            template = self.object.template
        else:
            try:
                template = ContractTemplate.objects.get(
                    slug=self.object.template.slug, language=lang)
            except ContractTemplate.DoesNotExist:
                template = self.object.template
        html = render_html_contract(
            template, self.object.customer, self.object.product)
        return HttpResponse(html)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        context = super(ContractAsHtmlView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context.update({
            'signature_ip': self.viewing_signature_ip,
        })

    @property
    def viewing_signature_ip(self):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=1)
        if contract.sign == True:
            return contract.signature_ip
```

In the moment, `sign()` method returns a Boolean argument, but it can't be triggered more than once. Hence, I can't use that method in my `view` with `if contract.sign == True:`. Anyway, `sign()` needs arguments and it is not a property. Is there another way to call `sign()` without triggering it another time? Could I use a sort of indicator or signal to do such thing?

In clear, `sign()` is used somewhere else in the program. I would like to say to `view_signature_ip()` method  if `sign()` is true, than return `contract.signature_ip`.

Comment: do you mean you can't use `{% if contract.sign %}` in your template? After calling sign() on your contract instance you could check the `contract.is_signed` attribute?

Comment: @Odi No, I can't. Your second question is very interesting. Could you develop a little bit more about 'you could check the `contract.is_signed` attrbute'? Could you build a full answer about that? Furthermore, I can't use `{% if contract.sign %}` because `sign` is not a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's see. You have a bug in your property method:

```
@property
def viewing_signature_ip(self):
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=1)
    if contract.sign == True:
        return contract.signature_ip
```

You are checking against a method definition, which is always True ;) If you want to check against the result of the method, you have to call it: `if contract.sign() == True` :-)

If you want to avoid calling sign, you could use the is_signed attribute of the contract instance: `if contract.is_signed`.

Another thing about the method property: `contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=1)` is called everytime you access the property, you might want to cache the result of the contract in a view attribute:

```
    _signature_ip = None

    @property
    def viewing_signature_ip(self):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        if self._signature_ip is not None:
             return self._signature_ip

        contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=1)

        self._signature_ip = contract.signature_ip if contract.is_signed else ''
        return self._signature_ip
```